# How can I sort 5 positive integers?

Tags: computer-science, pseudocode

I have a random collection of 5 unique integers ranging from 1 to 15 that I want to sort in ascending order from right to left.

```
Example input:  15 6 7 3 4
Desired output: 15 7 6 4 3
```

**Rules:**

We can only "see" the three rightmost integers at a time (7 3 4) in (15 6 **7 3 4**) and can only take actions on the rightmost integer in the array (4). We can also use up to 5 integer variables in the code.

**Possible actions:**

***putend***, the rightmost integer is placed at the leftmost position of the array

> (15 6 7 3 **4**) -> (**4** 15 6 7 3)

***swap***, the rightmost integer is swapped with the second integer. *Rightmost integer is moved one step left in the array.*

> (15 6 7 3 **4**) -> ( 15 6 7 **4** 3)

***double swap***, the rightmost integer is swapped with second element and then swapped with the third element. *Rightmost integer is moved 2 steps left in the array.*

> (15 6 7 3 **4**) -> (15 6 **4** 7 3).

---

**My attempt:**

```
while (not solved)
  if first element < 2nd element
    putend
  else if first element > 2nd element
    if first element > 3rd element
        double swap
    else
      swap
```

**Output:**

```
15 6 7 3 4  swap
15 6 7 4 3  putend
3 15 6 7 4  putend
4 3 15 6 7  swap
4 3 15 7 6  putend
6 4 3 15 7  putend
7 6 4 3 15 (problem here, triggers double swap but want putend and somehow detect that I am done)
```

Comment: @Tupteq I think I did. What am I missing?

Comment: @Kluddizz rules section is quite restrictive - none of quick sort or bubble sort will work because they require free access to the whole array.

Comment: @Tupteq Yeah, I missed that, sorry.

Comment: "We can also use up to 5 variables in the code" - Does this include the input array? Can our variables be arrays themselves?

Comment: "We can only "see" the three rightmost integers at a time" - Does this mean that there is no data-structure that holds the input array? Or does it mean that the code can only do conditional operations based upon the rightmost three values?

Comment: @Lenna basically, that array is "hidden" from us and we can only see three rightmost values at a time. hidden array: 15 6 7 3 4, we can only see 7 3 4 in the beginning. We can imagine that that is a visible array of length 3 whose contents are changed every time we call an action. So yeah, it means that we can only do operations on the rightmost three values. One possible way to see the whole array is to "cycle" through it by putting the first value at the end of the array and thereby moving the other values "forward".

Comment: Our variables can only be integers and the hidden and visible arrays do not count in the 5 variables limit.

Comment: @Clone Did you eve check my solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a working Python program to demonstrate algorithm, but I think it's as readable as pseudocode for everyone (I made code dead simple). Solution is quite brutal, but seems to be working. There's also lot of potential for further optimizations. I put descriptions in comment:

```py
x = [15, 12, 3, 2, 13]

def putend():
    x.append(x.pop(0))

def swap():
    x[0], x[1] = x[1], x[0]

def doubleswap():
    x[0], x[1], x[2] = x[1], x[2], x[0]


def put_smallest_back():
  smallest = min(x[0], x[1], x[2])
  if x[2] == smallest:
    # Move smallest to x[1]
    doubleswap()
  if x[1] == smallest:
    # Move smallest to x[0]
    swap()
  putend()

# Put back two smallest values of four to make sure two largest are in front
put_smallest_back()
put_smallest_back()

# Now two largest values are in three accessible cells
# Find and put back second largest
largest = max(x[0], x[1], x[2])
smallest = min(x[0], x[1], x[2])
if x[2] != largest and x[2] != smallest:
  doubleswap()
if x[1] != largest and x[1] != smallest:
  swap()
putend()

# Find and put back largest
# Largest is in x[0] or x[1]
if x[1] == largest:
  swap()

# Largest is in x[0]
putend()

# Two largest values are sorted
# Time to sort x[2]
if x[0] > x[1] and x[0] > x[2]:
  doubleswap()
elif x[1] > x[0] and x[1] > x[2]:
  swap()
  doubleswap()

# Last step, sort x[0] and x[1]
if x[0] > x[1]:
  swap()

# Voilla!
print(x)
```

I used `min()` and `max()` functions without defining them, but their implementation is trivial, especially they always operate on first three elements of collection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more solution. This time I created a `sort3()` utility function that sorts first three items. This greatly simplified algorithm and now doesn't require `min()`, `max()` nor any additional variables. Solution is fully functional Python code, but as easy to read as pseudocode:

```py
x = [5, 1, 13, 2, 10]

def putend():
    x.append(x.pop(0))

def swap():
    x[0], x[1] = x[1], x[0]

def doubleswap():
    x[0], x[1], x[2] = x[1], x[2], x[0]

# Sort first 3 elements ascending
def sort3():
    if x[1] > x[0]:  # Ensure larger of first two is x[0]
        swap()
    if x[0] > x[2]:  # If x[0] is largest, doublewsap it to x[2]
        doubleswap()
    if x[0] > x[1]:  # Largest value is in x[2], sort x[0] and x[1]
        swap()

# Put back smallest of first three items
sort3()
putend()

# Put back smallest of first three items again (x[2] is new item)
sort3()
putend()

# Now two largest values are in first three cells
# Find and put back second largest value
sort3()
swap()
putend()

# Put largest back
swap()
putend()

# Two largest values are sorted
# Time to sort the rest
sort3()

# Voila!
print(x)
```